# Swift HealthKit update Birthday

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, swift, healthkit

I want to update the birthday in Apple Health. But I don't know how.

This is my authorization func:

```
private func requestAuthorisationForHealthStore() {

    let dataTypesToWrite = [
        HKCharacteristicType.characteristicTypeForIdentifier(HKCharacteristicTypeIdentifierDateOfBirth),
        HKQuantityType.quantityTypeForIdentifier(HKQuantityTypeIdentifierBodyMass),
        HKQuantityType.quantityTypeForIdentifier(HKQuantityTypeIdentifierHeight)
    ]
    let dataTypesToRead = [
        HKCharacteristicType.characteristicTypeForIdentifier(HKCharacteristicTypeIdentifierDateOfBirth),
        HKQuantityType.quantityTypeForIdentifier(HKQuantityTypeIdentifierBodyMass),
        HKQuantityType.quantityTypeForIdentifier(HKQuantityTypeIdentifierHeight)
    ]

    self.healthStore?.requestAuthorizationToShareTypes(NSSet(array: dataTypesToWrite),
        readTypes: NSSet(array: dataTypesToRead), completion: {
            (success, error) in
            if success { println("User completed authorisation request.") }
            else { println("The user cancelled the authorisation request. \(error)") }
    })
}
```

For requesting the birthday I call my function:

```
func requestAgeAndUpdate() {

    var error: NSError?
    let dob = self.healthStore?.dateOfBirthWithError(&error)

    if error != nil {
        println("There was an error requesting the date of birth: \(error)")
        return
    }

    self.ageLabel.text = "\(dob)"
}
```

But how I can change/update the birthday programmatically?

Thanks for help!

Answer (score 3):

You cannot change these characteristics programatically.  The user must enter this data via the Health App.

From the [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/HealthKit/Reference/HKCharacteristicType_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/cl/HKCharacteristicType)

> The HKCharacteristicType class is a concrete subclass of the
>   HKObjectType class. HealthKit uses characteristic types to represent
>   data that does not typically change over time. Unlike the other object
>   types, characteristic types cannot be used to create new HealthKit
>   objects. Instead, users must enter and edit their characteristic data
>   using the Health app. Characteristic types are used only when asking
>   for permission to read data from the HealthKit store.

Answer (score 0):

HealthKit Framework Reference;

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/HealthKit/Reference/HealthKit_Framework/index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014707

> HealthKit objects can be divided into two main groups: characteristics
>   and samples. Characteristic objects represent data that typically does
>   not change. This data includes the user’s birthdate, blood type, and
>   biological sex. Your application cannot save characteristic data. The
>   user must enter or modify this data using the Health app.